# Calculate percentage of SQL Group BY

Tags: sql

The following SQL statement:

```
SELECT FTR, COUNT(FTR) 
FROM football_data 
WHERE Matchday >= '2019-01-18' 
GROUP BY FTR
```

Returns the following result:

[image: Result]

Now I'm trying to get a percentage for each of those COUNT(FTR)'s.

So the sum of those 3 numbers is 153. Now I would like to get the percentage of them

Comment: Can you specify for which database server you want to find solution? Or you really need a generic solution for any SQL database? It will be easier to find solution for specific database engine some specific SQL extensions can be used in the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions, if I understand correctly:

```
SELECT FTR, COUNT(*),
       COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as ratio
FROM football_data 
WHERE Matchday >= '2019-01-18'
GROUP BY FTR;
```